# How do templates work when using them as array dimensions?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, compilation

I tried to use tempaltes as array dimension value. I was puzzled when tried to specify wrong dimension as tempate argument. For example code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <int X, int Y>
void f(int a[X][Y]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y; ++j) {
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[2][2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
    f<2, 2>(a); // compilation succeeded
    f<10, 2>(a); // compilation succeeded
    f<2, 10>(a); // compilation FAILED
}
```

Why in the last case compilation fails, but in case <10, 2> it does not?

```
error: no matching function for call to 'f'
note: candidate function template not viable: no known conversion from 'int [2][2]' to 'int (*)[10]' for 1st argument
```

Comment: Because of [array decay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay), the outer-most dimension can be a bit fuzzy, but all of the inner dimensions must be exact.

Comment: Note, this is why `std::vector` exists and why using multi-dimensional arrays as arguments is not a great plan.

Comment: Note that because there aren't 10 rows in that outer dimension in `f<10, 2>(a);`, `for (int i = 0; i < X; ++i)` will send the program out of bounds at runtime.

Comment: @tadman, yes, I know, it just for an experiment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this result because `f(int a[X][Y])` is a **lie**.

Arrays are not first-class citizens in C++. You cannot pass an array as a function parameter by value. So when you write such parameter, it is silently adjusted to a pointer (the first level only). Thus the type of `a` is really `int (*)[Y]`.

Since there is no `X` in the type of `a`, absolutely any `X` will work.

If you want to enforce both `X` and `Y`, try passing the array *by reference*:

```
void f(int (&a)[X][Y])
```

or use `std::array`.

Comment: Addendum This also ruins C++17's improved template argument inference.  Without passing the array by reference as suggested in this answer, `f(a)` will infer a pointer to an array will miss out on the `X` argument.